# #1442 - Can't update table 'INSURANCE' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

Tags: mysql

I am creating trigger like this:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `trigger`;CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `trigger` AFTER UPDATE ON `INSURANCE` FOR EACH ROW update INSURANCE set LAT = 91.21
```

When I run this sql query I got this error.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, Rahul is right, you're defining recursive trigger that's not supported by MySQL. To achieve the result you want you can try using BEFORE UPDATE trigger and set value to LAT using

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `trigger`;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `trigger` BEFORE UPDATE ON `INSURANCE` FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.LAT =  91.21;
```

Comment: still getting same error

Comment: Please check you trigger definition carefully. it shouldn't contain any UPDATE statement, only SET NEW.LAT

Comment: why we are using Before Update instead of After Update

Comment: because you can't modify values of updated row in AFTER UPDATE (because update already happened, values are changed and you can only read OLD and NEW)

Answer (score 1):

Look at the line below, you are defining and updating the trigger on the same table which is also known as `Recursive Trigger` which is not supported in MySQL.

```
AFTER UPDATE ON `INSURANCE` 
FOR EACH ROW update INSURANCE
```